# one set of js logic works yet another doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**PS:** Id be very thankful for anyone to add a better title for this, I really couldnt think of anything else

So essentially I have this list logic: https://jsfiddle.net/ydtndwrv/10/, in short each item is linked with a description and an image.

I want to put **two** of these on one page like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6g3x149n/1/

```js
// -----------------START OF STYLING ELEMENT-----------------
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {

  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var siblings = this.parentNode.childNodes
    siblings.forEach(function(element) {

      if (element.className && element.className.indexOf('active') !== -1) {
        element.classList.remove("active");
      }
    })
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
// -----------------END OF STYLING ELEMENT-----------------


// -----------------START OF LOGIC ELEMENT-----------------

const desc_area = document.getElementById('description');
const image = document.querySelector('img');
const map = new Map();

// register item element as a key and object with corresponding description / image as value
map.set(item1, {
  desc: 'some description for item1',
  img: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/980681269859241984/-4cD6ouV_400x400.jpg'
});
map.set(item2, {
  desc: 'some description item2',
  img: 'https://78.media.tumblr.com/3d4a916d45190b2a58bec61f491cdb99/tumblr_p84af9767X1qhy6c9o1_500.gif'
});
map.set(item3, {
  desc: 'some  item3',
  img: 'https://cdn.europosters.eu/image/1300/32201.jpg'
});
map.set(item4, {
  desc: ' description for item4',
  img: 'https://www.scribblefun.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Pusheen-Coloring-Images.png'
});

map.set(item5, {
  desc: 'This item5 is cool',
  img: 'https://c1-zingpopculture.eb-cdn.com.au/merchandising/images/packshots/855db32a4fc24da2ba2ce821edd2a51e_Large.png'
});
map.set(item6, {
  desc: 'item6 displays attitude',
  img: 'https://c1-ebgames.eb-cdn.com.au/merchandising/images/packshots/969932eb9d274a57a59daf9e75319929_Medium.png'
});
map.set(item7, {
  desc: 'amazing item7 just breathtaking',
  img: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81GErgo2%2B8L._SY355_.jpg'
});
map.set(item8, {
  desc: ' item8 is an interesting conept',
  img: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2012/3849/products/4048862.jpg?v=1505815578'
});

// you can bind on click handler for example
const list = document.querySelector('ol');
list.addEventListener('click', event => {
  // if element that was registered in our map triggered the event
  if (map.has(event.target)) {
    // change text of description area
    desc_area.textContent = map.get(event.target).desc;
    // change src of the image
    image.src = map.get(event.target).img;
  }
});



// -----------------END OF LOGIC ELEMENT-----------------
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* containers  */

#content-working {
  margin: 20px;
}

* {
  font-family: Corbel;
}

#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#image,
#description,
#list {
  border: 1px solid #472836;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
}


/* list  */

#list {
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #9AD2CB;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#list ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#list li {
  padding: 5px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

#list li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #91f2e6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#list li:hover,
#list .active {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
  padding-left: 25px;
}


/* sub-container */

#image,
#description {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#image {
  background-color: #D7EBBA;
}

#image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#description {
  background-color: #FEFFBE;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 95px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-working">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="list">
      <ol>
        <li id="item1" class="item">items1</li>
        <li id="item2" class="item">items2</li>
        <li id="item3" class="item">items3</li>
        <li id="item4" class="item">items4</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div id="image-container">
      <div id="image">
        <img src="https://semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div id="description">
        just a placeholder text for when nothing has been chosen.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="list">
      <ol>
        <li id="item5" class="item">items5</li>
        <li id="item6" class="item">items6</li>
        <li id="item7" class="item">items7</li>
        <li id="item8" class="item">items8</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div id="image-container">
      <div id="image">
        <img src="https://semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div id="description">
        just a placeholder text for when nothing has been chosen.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The problem** is that I can't seem to get the second list working **BUT**  I have gotten very close to the problem.

**Initally** the problem is that I am using the same `description` and `img` in my js *thus* the second one has a problem of understanding which one goes where now.

> I have **tried** to *add* the second description:
>
> ```
> const desc_area2 = document.getElementById('description2');
> // and then when adding the event
> ..
>  desc_area2.textContent = map.get(event.target).desc;
> ```
>
> ..but then when I choose an item in the *first* list, **then** it
>   *does* change that said description content *yet* no effect with with the other list.

I'm not very proficient in *JS* thus I can't really figure out the solution.

Comment: "That's so cute." (My reaction when running the snippet)

Comment: Your main problem is that you are trying to use multiple elements (note that ids must be unique), but are using selectors that return only 1 element.

Comment: Some red flags I noticed: 1) Multiple elements have the same ID 2) The logic to update elements on click uses a description and image DOM element which is selected only once -How will each list know which is the correct item to update? I would recommend creating a function which accepts a DOM selector as an argument and handles the logic inside of that (therby isolating the scope and enabling multiple elements to coexsit on the page) 3) You are using `querySelector` when binding the events. This applies to only the first matched event so your second `ol` never gets an event listener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made the following modifications:

1. Changed `id` to `class` in both the CSS and the HTML, as ids must be unique
2. Used correct multiple selectors `.querySelectorAll`, `.getElementsByClassName`, and `.forEach` when applicable.
3. Removed your variables `const desc_area` and `const image` to use some code in the `.forEach` instead.

Here is a snippet where the multiple elements are working *cutely*:
(See comments in my code for more details about the JS modifications, plus some suggestions!)

```js
// -----------------START OF STYLING ELEMENT-----------------
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {

  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var siblings = this.parentNode.childNodes
    siblings.forEach(function(element) {

      if (element.className){  // && element.className.indexOf('active') !== -1) { // TAKIT: Removed, see suggestion below
        if (element.classList.contains('active')) // TAKIT: Suggestion: Easier, and better readability!
          element.classList.remove("active");
      }
    })
    this.classList.add("active"); // TAKIT: Suggestion instead of this.className += " active";
  });
}
// -----------------END OF STYLING ELEMENT-----------------


// -----------------START OF LOGIC ELEMENT-----------------


const map = new Map();
// register item element as a key and object with corresponding description / image as value
map.set(item1, {
  desc: 'some description for item1',
  img: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/980681269859241984/-4cD6ouV_400x400.jpg'
});
map.set(item2, {
  desc: 'some description item2',
  img: 'https://78.media.tumblr.com/3d4a916d45190b2a58bec61f491cdb99/tumblr_p84af9767X1qhy6c9o1_500.gif'
});
map.set(item3, {
  desc: 'some  item3',
  img: 'https://cdn.europosters.eu/image/1300/32201.jpg'
});
map.set(item4, {
  desc: ' description for item4',
  img: 'https://www.scribblefun.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Pusheen-Coloring-Images.png'
});

map.set(item5, {
  desc: 'This item5 is cool',
  img: 'https://c1-zingpopculture.eb-cdn.com.au/merchandising/images/packshots/855db32a4fc24da2ba2ce821edd2a51e_Large.png'
});
map.set(item6, {
  desc: 'item6 displays attitude',
  img: 'https://c1-ebgames.eb-cdn.com.au/merchandising/images/packshots/969932eb9d274a57a59daf9e75319929_Medium.png'
});
map.set(item7, {
  desc: 'amazing item7 just breathtaking',
  img: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81GErgo2%2B8L._SY355_.jpg'
});
map.set(item8, {
  desc: ' item8 is an interesting conept',
  img: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2012/3849/products/4048862.jpg?v=1505815578'
});

// you can bind on click handler for example
const list = document.querySelectorAll('ol'); // TAKIT: Modified to return multiple elements
list.forEach(function() { // TAKIT: Added to manage the multiple elements
  this.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // if element that was registered in our map triggered the event
    if (map.has(event.target)) {
      var wrapper = event.target.closest('.wrapper'); // TAKIT: Get parent wrapper
      // change text of description area
      wrapper.querySelector('.description').textContent = map.get(event.target).desc; // TAKIT: Modified
      // change src of the image
      wrapper.querySelector('img').src = map.get(event.target).img; // TAKIT: Modified
    }
  });
});



// -----------------END OF LOGIC ELEMENT-----------------
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* containers  */

#content-working {
  margin: 20px;
}

* {
  font-family: Corbel;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image,
.description,
.list {
  border: 1px solid #472836;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
}


/* list  */

.list {
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #9AD2CB;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.list ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list li {
  padding: 5px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.list li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #91f2e6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.list li:hover,
.list .active {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
  padding-left: 25px;
}


/* sub-container */

.image,
.description {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.image {
  background-color: #D7EBBA;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.description {
  background-color: #FEFFBE;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 95px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-working">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="list">
      <ol>
        <li id="item1" class="item">items1</li>
        <li id="item2" class="item">items2</li>
        <li id="item3" class="item">items3</li>
        <li id="item4" class="item">items4</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        just a placeholder text for when nothing has been chosen.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="list">
      <ol>
        <li id="item5" class="item">items5</li>
        <li id="item6" class="item">items6</li>
        <li id="item7" class="item">items7</li>
        <li id="item8" class="item">items8</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        just a placeholder text for when nothing has been chosen.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!